# Minify Javascript and CSS Files Not Included In A Bundle

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to minify the Javascript and CSS files in my MVC project.  I succeeded in doing so with the files that are contained in Bundles.  However, the js and css files not included in Bundles are not being minified.  Currently I am only Bundling the files in _Layouts and other widely used Views, meaning that any js and css files that are only used on one page are not being minified.  Initially I thought I may need to create smaller Bundles for each of these individual Views that have specific js and css files that they use, but that sounded too cumbersome and did not seem correct.  I was hoping that someone would be able to help me find a way to minify js and css files in a View that are not contained in a Bundle.

Comment: lots of ways to do it, for example here's an [npm package called minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify)

Comment: it depends on your task manager, if any: I use Gulp.js to manage styles, etc.: I don’t think that running a single npm package could be better than this; it’s lighter than Webpack, but you should always install node_modules; otherwise, I’m sure there are web services who let you to cut and paste your code to have it minified